# How to make drop-down menu appear over slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have my drop down menu directly above the slideshow. Because of this, the sub-menus get hidden behind the slideshow when I hover over the menu. I would like the sub-menus to appear over the slideshow.

Slideshow Code

```
var o=String.fromCharCode(60);var c=String.fromCharCode(62)
document.write(o+'iframe sr'+'c="http://slideful.com/vid.htm"      frameborder="0" sty'+'le="border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;width:900px;height:563px;"     allowtransparency="true"'+c+o+'/iframe'+c)
```

Dropdown Code

```
.tab {
  font-family: arial, verdana, san-serif; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
.asd {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, verdana, san-serif;
  font-size: 13px; 
  color:#4234ff;
}

/*****remove the list style****/
#nav {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  list-style:none;
}   

/*****LI display inline *****/
#nav li {
  float:left; 
  display:block; 
  width:100px;
  background:#1E5B91;
  position:relative;
  z-index:500; 
  margin:0 1px;
}

/*****parent menu*****/
#nav li a {
  display:block; 
  padding:8px 5px 0 5px; 
  font-weight:700; 
  height:23px; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center; 
  color:#ffeecc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color:#470020;
}

#nav a.selected { /* style for default selected value */ 
  color:#4234ff;
}
#nav ul { /* submenu */ 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  display:none; 
  margin:0 0 0 -1px;
  padding:0; 
  list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
  width:100px; 
  float:left; 
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul a { /* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */
  display:block; 
  height:15px;
  padding: 8px 5px; 
  color:#ff7777;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;    
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

Dropdown jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#nav li').hover(function () {
  $('ul', this).slideDown(350); //show its submenu
  }, function () {
    $('ul', this).slideUp(350); //hide its submenu
  });
});
```

Dropdown HTML

```
<input type=hidden name=arav value="1*#*#*2">
  <ul id='nav'>
    <li><a href='#'>SHOP</a>
        <ul>
          <li style='background-color:#b0c4de;'><a href=http://link.com>Womens</a></li>
          <li style='background-color:#bebebe;'><a href=http://link.com>Mens</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</input
```

I would like my submenus that are shown when you hover over the "Shop" button to show up over the slideshow that is below it. They hide under it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  #nav ul { /* submenu */ 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  display:none; 
  margin:0 0 0 -1px;
  padding:0; 
  list-style:none;
  z-index:9999;
}

#nav ul li {
  width:100px; 
  float:left; 
  z-index:9999;
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Using z-index you can achieve this.

Comment: already tried that and just did again to make sure, it didn't work.

Comment: can you post a link to your live page?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to wrap your iframe and give that container a z-index value of 1 and the navigation container should have a z-index value of 2.

You will also need to set the position property value to relative for both of these containers.

```
#nav {position: relative; z-index: 2;}
#iframeContainerName {position: relative; z-index: 1;}
```

Also, you may want to look into other ways of implementing the slideshow. Using document.write has potential issues: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would work if you're viewing your slideshow as in your code above (I'm not very familiar with Javascript or how this would work with iframes).

However, I came here also searching for answers, so I will post my solution in the case that it may help anyone who finds this page as I did.

I had the same issue, although my slideshow code looked like this.

```
<ul class="bjqs">
<li><img src="kjdsajkdhsja.png"></li>
</ul>
```

I found that changing the z-index to all the elements relating to the slideshow to lower than the drop down elements would not work - until I made my images background images in divs, as so:

```
<ul class="bjqs">
<li><div style="background-image:url(kjdsajkdhsja.png);width:200px;height:75px;"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Crummy workaround, but it did me fine for the project I was on.

Answer (score 0):

For showing dropdown menu over slide show

write the code in css where you have written dropdown menu code

`.dropdown_menu { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }`

it will work